# how to filter object using element in array in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How to get objects from a collection by using match with multiple values of an array.For ex: I have below data in a collection

```
    { "_id" : ObjectId("512bc95fe835e68f199c8686"), "author" : "dave", "score" : 80, "views" : 100 }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("512bc962e835e68f199c8687"), "author" : "dave", "score" : 85, "views" : 521 }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("55f5a192d4bede9ac365b257"), "author" : "ahn", "score" : 60, "views" : 1000 }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("55f5a192d4bede9ac365b258"), "author" : "li", "score" : 55, "views" : 5000 }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("55f5a1d3d4bede9ac365b259"), "author" : "annT", "score" : 60, "views" : 50 }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("55f5a1d3d4bede9ac365b25a"), "author" : "li", "score" : 94, "views" : 999 }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("55f5a1d3d4bede9ac365b25b"), "author" : "ty", "score" : 95, "views" : 1000 }
```

Now i get an array as input

```
{"annT","ahn","ty"}
```

can it do something like this to get all the records with these authors

```
db.articles.aggregate(
[ { $match : { author : {"annT","ahn","ty"} } } ]
);
```

This input array length varies according to user selection.Is there any better way to get this records? ThanYou in advance

Comment: How do you filter these records, according to which field and which value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$in` operator to match a particular field agains an array of value.

```
db.posts.find({author: {$in: ["annT","ahn","ty"]}})
```